# how to read different sheets in a csv file using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Am maintaining the data in different sheets in a csv file,but now i wanted to read this through jmeter .
i know how to read single csv file in jmeter , so need help to read different sheets in a single csv file.

Can anyone please help to get solution for this ?

Comment: Any feedback on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter only reads CSV so you would need to save each sheet as CSV.

You could try otherwise with a setup Thread group and custom code (Beanshell or JSR223) that takes this excel and extracts each sheet into a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

CSV file is not created for that : CSV file should contains only one sheet. 
As @PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE suggests, export every sheet to an other csv file.